# Understanding Exceptional Points

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, topology, two-level-system

Exceptional points occur generically in eigenvalue problems that depend on a parameter.
By variation of such parameter (usually into the complex plane) one can generically find
points where eigenvalues coincide. In [Weiss' review of exceptional points](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.7536)

I found a demonstration of exceptional points is particularly confusing: [image]

The energy levels are Riemann sheets in complex parameter ($\lambda$) space, typically denoted as $E(\lambda)$ are identical at $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. However, the figure shows that two energy levels are identical at a whole branch cut. Is something misleading here or I don't really understand the definition of exceptional points?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the **definition of exceptional points**, the easiest way to think about them is that the matrix of the eigenvalue problem is not diagonalizable there. They called “points” since almost all matrices are diagonalizable (mathematically: diagonalisable matrices are dense on the complex matrices), so they are pretty rare and one generally has to work hard to realize one in physical systems (hence “exceptional”).

With regards to the **branch cuts**: An important point to note is that exceptional points only occur in non-Hermitian matrices, so they generally have **complex eigenvalues**. What is shown in the plots are the real and imaginary part of the eigenvalue. If the real part has a branch cut, the imaginary part is generally not degenerate. And vice versa: the imaginary part has a branch cut where the real part does not. The only true degeneracy (i.e. where both real and imaginary part are degenerate) is then the point where **the two branch cuts touch each other**. This is the exceptional point.

Note that this argument about the structure of the parameter space may have to be adjusted in the presence of symmetries.

Answer (score -1):

Most QT books have a chapter of higher order perturbation theory in case of degeneration.

Exact quantum theory and the working numerical examples  sometimes produce parametrized eigenvalue curves in terms of an external field with an adjustible strenght, exactly soluble or to be aproximated by linear perturbation methods.

In all cases of level crossing, in the parameter point of level crossing, the higher order approximations cut the linear crossing of a pair of lines (approximately to first order) into a pair of separated hyperbolas, tangent to the lines.

The reason is simple: Any accidental generation of a spectral point into a finite dimensional subspace  greater 1, that is not fixed by a symmetry group of the total hamiltonian, is instable with respect to tiny perturbations. Already coupling charges to the external e.m. vacuum or thermal field destroys degeneration at very low perturbation energy level, e.g. by acoustic noise.

A classical case in solid state theory are the $\omega_i(k)$ surfaces of acoustic and optical phonons, describing volume deplacement waves and oscillations of sublattices of different atom species against each other.

Even if the phonon spectra are discrete for a finite body, curves are smooth and the level crossing is removed into separated mode curves: the osciallation mode types in a lattice cell have completely reorganized in cases, where different modes have the same frequency.

Optical phonons interact strongly with em waves of the same wavelenght. For wavelengths approximating the latice constant, the choice of a basis for particle coordinates in groups of lattice cells becomes meaningless and so does the representation of modes in distinct groups organized in the inifinite wavelenght limit.